# PHP page timed out, now browser is putting www in front of my url

Tags: redirect, local, hosts

I was running a very time consuming script on my localhost, and I thought I'd correctly set it up to not time out using this code: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`

However, before the 5 minutes was up, my internet service provider (BT) annoyingly redirected me to a "We can't find your page" page. I've changed a preference to stop them from doing this again.

My script was running on the URL "myproject.local/script.php". I've set up my computer using the hosts file to direct anything that points to myproject.local to the folder: Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject

The problem now, is that whenever I type myproject.local, I get redirected to www.myproject.local and the browser fails to find the page. I have to type http://myproject.local in order for it to find the correct page.

NB The very first time I set up myproject.local (months ago) and went to it in the browser, my browser asked me "Did you mean http://myproject.local?" and I clicked yes, and it remembered it ever since. That is, up until now.

Can anyone advise how I can get my browser to take me http://myproject.local without always having to type http:// (The browser I'm having trouble with is Firefox)